# Jquery compatibility with Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code underneath works perfectly fine on Chrome, but not on Firefox 39.0. Any suggestions on why not? Does the problem lie with with the `display:none` or with the `click` function?

HTML

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
</head

<body>
<a class="showSingle" target="1">
    <p style="text-align:center;">Show 1</p>
</a>

<a class="showSingle" target="2">
    <p style="text-align:center;">Show 2</p>
</a>

<a class="showSingle" target="3">
    <p style="text-align:center;">Show 3</p>
</a>

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">
    <p>test1</p>
</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv" style="display:none">
    <p>test2</p>
</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv" style="display:none">
    <p>test3</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.showSingle').click(function () {
        jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
        jQuery('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Why are you using the target attribute for data storage?

Comment: Works for me too. What errors do you get in FF when you run it?

Comment: Begin ruling out possibilities by adding debugging statements within your code. Does the click event happen? If yes, remove it and instead just get the value of the attribute. Does it contain what it should?

Comment: @Jonakemon No, there's no possible way firefox wouldn't support a jquery click event binding. something else is happening, such as invalid html or similar. (the html you provided is broken, btw. Missing `>` on `<head`)

Comment: Show hide is irrelevant if the click event isn't happening.

Answer (score 1):

check your proxy settings in firefox and make sure you can get to http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js

Comment: ouch, that's what I get for trying to help out when there is some secret info missing from the question.